# Access denied on switching to other frame (.Net WebBrowser, MsHTML) cross-domain Exception

Tags: c#, webbrowser-control, mshtml, ihtmldocument2

i'm trying to switch for another frame (With no name or id) but getting Exception.

```
object index = 0;
var frame = (mshtml.IHTMLWindow2)workDocument.frames.item(ref index);
frameDocument = (mshtml.IHTMLDocument2)frame.document; // Exception.
```

Tried other way but the same exception:

```
webBrowser.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementById("userName").SetAttribute("value", username);
webBrowser.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementById("userPassword").SetAttribute("value", password);
webBrowser.Document.Window.Frames[0].Document.GetElementById("login").InvokeMember("click");
```

**Exception:**

> Access is denied. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80070005
>   (E_ACCESSDENIED))

i understand that is a **cross-domain** reason, do we have solution for that cases

Thank's

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can catch and ignore the exception, or tweak the security settings to allow cross-domain scripting:

- derive a class from WebBrowser
- [create a nested class derived from WebBrowser.WebBrowserSite](https://jiangsheng.net/2013/07/17/howto-ignoring-web-browser-certificate-errors-in-webbrowser-host/) (the only way you can derive from the nested class)
- override CreateWebBrowserSiteBase and return a new instance of your webbrowser site.
- implement IServiceProvider on the webbrowser site
- implement IServiceProvider.QueryService so it returns an IInternetHostSecurityManager implementation when the SID_SInternetHostSecurityManager service is requested
- handle IInternetHostSecurityManager.GetSecurityId and return the same domain id for all sites you want to cross-domain scripting to work with. For other web sites, give each domain a different id. Note this opens your application to cross-domain scripting attacks so you need to trust all domains sharing the same id.
- use the new webbrowser in the form